# HTML: text, headlines, sublines

Tags: html, css, tags

I have some question about html-style

At the moment I use following style:

```
<h2>Headline</h2>
<h4>Subline</h4>
<p>text
tzext
text
text
</p>
```

Is there a recommand html tag that only defines text and I could define headings myself, somehow like this:

```
<text class="headline">Headline</text>
<text class="subline">Subline</text>
<text>
....
.....
</text>
```

Wouldn't this be better style?

How do you do this?

Regards

Comment: First one is preferable and semantically better

Comment: You must use CSS to do this. No html tag, but I don't know much about html 5. Maybe in that way you can do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headings use [`<h1>` through `<h6>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements). You really shouldn't use anything else for headings as these tags exist specifically for this task, If you have multiple sets of headings on a page, you should group them in the [`<hgroup>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-hgroup-element) and [`<header>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-header-element) tags.

Keep in mind your code has to be semantic, and make sense. When screen readers come across your site, they need to understand where the important headings are. If everybody just used generic tags, it would be impossible for accessibility to make sense of your page. The same goes with search engines and any other form of programmatic consumption of your data.

Comment: Hi, at the moment I use something like this for the header:
<header><img /><hgroup><h1></h1><h2></h2></hgroup></header>
Is this legitim?

Comment: That's not too bad. Though I personally would probably not put an image tag in there unless it were absolutely necessary.

Comment: How do you implement the logo?

Comment: @dev.pus Without seeing your page and knowing how crucial the image is, I cannot answer that.

Comment: @dev.pus "The <header> element should be used as a container for introductory content or set of navigational links." You can place a logo in another div around it, but as Jonathan says it is not optimal to place your logo(img) into the <header> area

Answer (score 2):

Using h1/2/3/4 tags is the best way to do it. You can also give a h1 a class like so:

```
<h1 class="yourclass">
```

you can then select that specific h1 in your css by selecting your h1 class

```
.youclass{your css}
```

, or you can select all h1's on your page in css by just type

```
h1{ your css here}.
```

Answer (score 0):

in html 5 you have new html elements for header, footer, also paragraphs...more cool features are there. You should check out..This helps semantics as well...

Answer (score 0):

From [the CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html):

> Note. CSS gives so much power to the "class" attribute, that authors could conceivably design their own "document language" based on elements with almost no associated presentation (such as DIV and SPAN in HTML) and assigning style information through the "class" attribute. Authors should avoid this practice since the structural elements of a document language often have recognized and accepted meanings and author-defined classes may not.

There is more to a webpage then the way it looks. People access them with screen readers. Search engines index them. Tables of contents are automatically generated for them. etc.

So no. Hundreds of `<text>` elements would not be better style.

Your original example isn't very good either. You have no `<h3>` (I'm assuming the `<h1>` appears before the snippit). Don't skip heading levels.

If the `<h4>` is supposed to be a subtitle for the heading (rather then the start of a subsection within it) then you should be looking to use [`<hgroup>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-hgroup-element.html#the-hgroup-element) too.

Answer (score 0):

If u use CSS it would be better as it reduces the number of lines required to HTML file. There
are many ty